How to update internal data in a CRAN package with .rda outputs from an internal package?
Background
I have (almost) finished the development of package A, which is an internal package that has access to raw data, transform and export different list objects as .rda files. Assuming they are called: list_1.rda and list_2.rda.
These files act as input data for another package B, a golem style Shiny package which is planned to be submitted to CRAN once it's completed.
Different purposes of data require different way to handle them when developing a package. In the book R Package (2e), page 100, Hadley wrote:

If you want to store R objects and make them available to the user, put them in data/. (X)
If you want to store R objects for your own use as a developer, put them in R/sysdata.rda. (V)

In my case, I'd prefer the second way (V), as it suits the nature of the relationship better between package A and B, and these lists are still relatively raw and act as input for modelling, so I'd like users to interact with the final transformed outputs via the shiny app.
Issue
Again, in the book R Package (2e), page 106, Hadley wrote:

Unlike data/, where you use one .rda file per exported data object, you store all of your internal data objects together in the single file R/sysdata.rda.

I am not too clear what I should do here. I have created a simple package whereto to demonstrate my question. Below is the file structure of it:
.
├── DESCRIPTION
├── LICENSE
├── LICENSE.md
├── man
│   └── show_me_the_data.Rd
├── NAMESPACE
├── R
│   ├── show_me_the_data.R
│   ├── sysdata.R
│   └── sysdata.rda
└── whereto.Rproj

The sysdata.R is:
# Output 1 from the package A:
df_1 <- load(file = "C:/Users/Downloads/df_1.rda")

# Output 2 from the package A:
df_2 <- load(file = "C:/Users/Downloads/df_2.rda")

usethis::use_data(df_1, df_2, internal = TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)

and the sysdata.rda is the internal data that made available in package B.
There is also a function called show_me_the_data(), saved in the file with the same name. It is a simple function to check if the package whereto can read and use the data x from df_1:
#' Test function
#' @export

show_me_the_data <- function() {x}

x is a list:
> x
$my_data
   name
1  Eric
2   Tui
3 Maple

$human
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

The simple function successfully returned the x as defined above. Given this context, I am just wondering:

Should I merge all .rda files from package A into one sysdata.rda file, then copy and paste it to package B's R/ folder?
If I wish to do it in an automated fashion, where is the best place to keep and execute the working code sysdata.R when the data need to be updated?

Please note that the outputs of package A is stored internally, so unfortunately they can't be passed from A to B as if they are two CRAN packages would do. I need to bridge this step, and that's the core of my question.

I answered the previous version of your question, but you deleted it.  It would have been better to edit that question as above.  I've voted to close this version, as it is asking more about opinion now, and less about technical methods.

Sorry I’m still new here, I’ll reedit this question after it is closed.

You don't need to wait for it to be closed -- you can edit it anytime to clarify it.

Well, now it's closed, here's some advice:  Don't ask questions like "Should I ..." or "where is the best place ...", because those are looking for opinions.  That kind of question is fine in a place like the R-help mailing list, but on SO, you should ask questions like "Why doesn't this do what I thought it would?" or "How do I do this?"  Keep it to just one topic (but feel free to ask other topics in other questions).

Thank you for your advice. I have edited the question and hopefully it meets the standards; and a valuable lesson for the future.
